# Option Pricing - Incorrect price outcome for Out of the Money (OTM) calls

Tags: r, data.table

I have the options data for a stock -

```
structure(list(Curr_Date = structure(c(18904L, 18904L, 18904L, 
18904L, 18904L, 18904L, 18904L, 18904L, 18904L), class = c("IDate", 
"Date")), ticker = c("GOLD", "GOLD", "GOLD", "GOLD", "GOLD", 
"GOLD", "GOLD", "GOLD", "GOLD"), ExpDate = structure(c(18915L, 
18915L, 19013L, 19013L, 19013L, 19377L, 19377L, 19377L, 19377L
), class = c("IDate", "Date")), Strike = c(18, 30, 10, 30, 40, 
10, 18, 30, 40), Option_Type = c("calls", "calls", "calls", "calls", 
"calls", "calls", "calls", "calls", "calls"), OI = c(3570L, 341L, 
723L, 68772L, 26302L, 1731L, 15662L, 37274L, 13215L), Vol = c(1L, 
1L, 5L, 40L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 5L), ask = c(0.56, 0.01, 8.6, 0.07, 
0.04, 10, 2.8, 0.51, 0.21), bid = c(0.54, 0, 8.2, 0.06, 0.03, 
8.05, 2.58, 0.48, 0.2), StockPrice = c(18.23, 18.23, 18.23, 18.23, 
18.23, 18.23, 18.23, 18.23, 18.23), days2exp = c(0.0301369863013699, 
0.0301369863013699, 0.298630136986301, 0.298630136986301, 0.298630136986301, 
1.2958904109589, 1.2958904109589, 1.2958904109589, 1.2958904109589
), calculated_price = c(0.53, 0, 8.27, 0, 0, 8.5, 2.87, 0.36, 
0.06)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x562667c9eac0>)
```

which looks like -

```
    Curr_Date ticker    ExpDate Strike Option_Type    OI Vol   ask  bid StockPrice   days2exp calculated_price
1: 2021-10-04   GOLD 2021-10-15     18       calls  3570   1  0.56 0.54      18.23 0.03013699             0.53
2: 2021-10-04   GOLD 2021-10-15     30       calls   341   1  0.01 0.00      18.23 0.03013699             0.00
3: 2021-10-04   GOLD 2022-01-21     10       calls   723   5  8.60 8.20      18.23 0.29863014             8.27
4: 2021-10-04   GOLD 2022-01-21     30       calls 68772  40  0.07 0.06      18.23 0.29863014             0.00
5: 2021-10-04   GOLD 2022-01-21     40       calls 26302   1  0.04 0.03      18.23 0.29863014             0.00
6: 2021-10-04   GOLD 2023-01-20     10       calls  1731   1 10.00 8.05      18.23 1.29589041             8.50
7: 2021-10-04   GOLD 2023-01-20     18       calls 15662   2  2.80 2.58      18.23 1.29589041             2.87
8: 2021-10-04   GOLD 2023-01-20     30       calls 37274   4  0.51 0.48      18.23 1.29589041             0.36
9: 2021-10-04   GOLD 2023-01-20     40       calls 13215   5  0.21 0.20      18.23 1.29589041             0.06
```

As it can be seen in column `calculated_price`, the OTM (out of the money) calls are hugely underpriced compared to bid or ask price. I have used the below formulas to calculate the expected price of an option.

```
r = 0.0148 # Risk free rate
v = 0.3188 # Historic volatility of 252 trading days
b = 0.02 # TTM yeild
dt[, d1 := ((log(StockPrice/Strike)) + (r - b + (v^2)/2) * days2exp)/(v * (sqrt(days2exp)))]
dt[, d2 := d1 - v * (sqrt(days2exp))]
dt[, calculated_price := round(StockPrice * pnorm(d1) - Strike*exp(-r * days2exp)*pnorm(d2), 2)]
```

Can someone point me out what is wrong with these formulas and how to correct the mispricing?

The expected result is - The values in column `calculated_price` should be between the market price in `bid` and `ask` columns.

Thanks!

Comment: Your math is likely correct but that still does not mean that the _law of one price_ has been violated: the _bid_ and _ask_ quotes may be _stale_ and hence not fully reflect _current_ parameters as your calculation does.

Comment: This cannot be a coincidence, since this mispricing is there for almost all options across the board. All the OTM calls and puts are hugely underpriced using these formulas. There must be something I am missing. I forgot to mention, that the last trading day had the volume for these options, so the chances of these prices being stale is slim. Market makers must be setting these prices up due to some reason.

Comment: are you using historical vol to price the options? you should be using implied vol to get prices inside the bid-ask, which is like a chicken and egg problem. what are u trying to do ultimately?

Comment: Yes, I had used historical vol for pricing. However, I now came to know that I should be using implied vol instead. Unfortunately, finding implied volatility is not an easy task without creating a vol surface and getting the correct continuous risk-free rate and continuous dividend (dividend schedule). I will appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.